# How to convert SVG to PNG or JPG/JPEG files in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, frontend

How can I convert SVG files to png,jpg or jpeg Files in React.js Because I am trying to send my files to server and server only accepts jpg/jpeg or png. Any help? I only need files in one of these types. I don't need them in url or blob.

[The screenshot of file in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvPbK.png)

I searched all over the place. There are some but either the solution is for backend or javascript with dom

```
 const [fileImages, setFileImages] = useState<File[]>([]);
  const { state } = useAssetReportContext();

  const charts = state.chartsList.map(({ url, fileName }) => ({
    url,
    fileName,
  }));
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImages = () => {
      charts.map(({ url, fileName }) => {
        fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.blob())
          .then(
            (blob) =>
              new File([blob], `${fileName}`, {
                type: blob.type,
              })
          )
          .then((file) => {
            setFileImages((prev) => [...prev, file]);
          });
      });
    };
    fetchImages();
  }, [state.chartsList.length]);
```

Comment: The screenshot isn't helpful.  Yet, please post any code you have showing your attempt at solving the problem (even if not working).

Comment: Actually I am taking these svg images by ref of charts in the Virtual Dom and wanna send these to the server

Comment: *"or javascript with dom"* Why is that a problem?

Comment: @gre_gor I couldn't achieve what I want by that

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'convert-svg-to-png' library.
[This is the npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-svg-to-png)

Then import it:

```
const { convertFile }  = require('convert-svg-to-png');
```

Then use the following code:

```
(async() => {
  const inputFilePath = '/path/to/my-image.svg';
  const outputFilePath = await convertFile(inputFilePath);

  console.log(outputFilePath);
  //=> "/path/to/my-image.png"
})();
```

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: isn't this for node.js? I need something for react.js

Comment: That is for React.js, You just install the library and add that code to your react js file